# Retrieve only on column in filter in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

how I get get only one column of my model using filter

```
ids = model1.objects.filter(key=value)
return model2.objects.filter(column__in=ids)
```

in above example first filter should return list of ids of model1
and in second example data will be return using in of 1st result ids

NOTE: model1 it's having number of field and one is id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only some columns using [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) or [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```py
ids = Model1.objects.filter(key=value).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

However, if you are going to filter on that, then this query is redundant at all (if I properly understand your schema).

Consider the following two models:

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model2(models.Model):
    m1_ref = models.ForeignKey(Model1, models.CASCADE)
```

Then two following queries are equivalent (but first is slower):

```py
ids = Model1.objects.filter(name=value).values_list('pk', flat=True)
result = Model2.objects.filter(m1_ref__in=ids)
```

and

```py
result = Model2.objects.filter(m1_ref__name=value)
```